# Lazarus FPC refusing a 64-bit value for AND op in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, freepascal, lazarus

The following won't compile:

```
and rax, $7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I've tried making the value a constant, even cast as a qword, but the compiler throws "dword value exceeds bounds."

Of course, this is a qword, not a dword. How do I get the compiler to realize this?

As a note, the 64-bit code is otherwise compiling and running correctly.

I have the latest Lazarus release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no variant of `AND` in the x86 instruction set that takes an `imm64` operand. You can use `mov r64, imm64` followed by `and r/m64, r64`.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting that. Thank you.

Comment: @IanC: Making immediate operands 64bit in long mode would have bloated code a lot.  Introducing a lot of new opcodes with imm64 operands would have used up a lot of opcode space and added complexity to the decoders.